# how to add comment like this before a function or class in emacs

Tags: templates, emacs

After googling, I still cannot find a answer how to do this in emacs?

```
/** @mainpage 
 *
 *  This document details .
 *
 *
 *  @section ma_ 
 *  @image html 
 *
 *  @section si_ 
 *  @image html 
 *
 */

class xxx {
};
```

Comment: What is the part that you want to add? Just `/* */`, or everything in between as well?

Comment: add /* */ part.